# Enable rainbow parentheses

Tags: parentheses, slime

0.4 on Windows and want to enable rainbow parentheses, but I can't find the ticking box under global options-> code-> display as shown in the most tutorials. Do I need a specific package for that?. This option also isn't in the code dropdown menu.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It seems that I deleted the first words :). I have R Studio on my windows machine an R version 4.0.4

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post corrections as comments, but edit your question.